# Magento cron job

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-cron

I was trying to activate the cron job in my store and I received this error

> [root@sitesmagento-1 onyxtrade]# PHP Warning: 
>   include_once(phpseclib/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /var/www/html/onyxtrade/app/Mage.php on line 56

I used the command

```
sh /path/to/your/magento/site/root/cron.sh
```

I am using version 1.9.4 of magento, 
Can someone help me start the cron job?

Answer (score 0):

Hapend the same to me when i run the indexer. So i cheked in the app/Mage.php on line 56 and i saw that on the latest update to Magento 1.9.4.5 it added these lines:

```
include_once "phpseclib/bootstrap.php";
include_once "mcryptcompat/mcrypt.php";
```

So i just replaced those lines with the path to bootstrap.php and Mccrypt.php:

```
include_once "app/bootstrap.php";
include_once "lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php";
```

Worked for me, hope it helps.